# ActiveRecord::Relation equivalent method to Array#delete_at(index)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

ActiveRecord::Relation equivalent method to Array#delete_at(index)? *Perhaps also suggest an alternative implementation.*

```
results = Agent.where(target_industry: target_industry)

if !target_specialty.empty?
  results.map.with_index do |result, index| 
    unless target_specialty.include?(result.target_specialty_1) || 
           target_specialty.include?(result.target_specialty_2) || 
           target_specialty.include?(result.target_specialty_3)

      results.delete_at(index)
    end
  end
end

@result = results
```

Basically if a `target_specialty` filters are POST'd, then REMOVE/DELETE all the ROWS from the ActiveRecord::Relation `results` WHERE target_specialty_1/2/3 does not include Array#target_specialty. Finally send back `@result = results` to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [Array#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-select) method, which will remove all the items on the list which don't check against a condition:

```
results.select do |result| 
  target_specialty.include?(result.target_specialty_1) || 
  target_specialty.include?(result.target_specialty_2) || 
  target_specialty.include?(result.target_specialty_3)
end
```

Which also results in a much cleaner code :)

Comment: Yep this is what I needed. Forgot about Array#select -- Perfect Thanks! =D

Answer (score 3):

This only fetches records from the database where none of `target_specialty_x` matches any of the values from `target_specialty`:

```
results.where.not(
  target_specialty1: target_specialty,
  target_specialty2: target_specialty,
  target_specialty3: target_specialty
)
```

This way, you don't need to delete any items from the relation since they're not returned by the database in the first place.

Comment: This isn't what I want --- I'm not actually trying to DELETE the row from the TABLE. I am just trying to DELETE/REMOVE the row from the RESULT . The table should not be affected. This is doing a SQL DELETE.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It is not actually removing database rows anymore.

Comment: It depends on how many results there are in the database. If there are too many, the non-DB solution fetches all of them from the database, loads them into memory, and then throws away a lot of them. If the database is large enough, the application could run out of memory. The database solution is aimed towards scalability.

Comment: Thank you for adding that. The actual `Agent.where` has other restraints. And a limit of 50 records. But I see your point. Thanks again!